# Integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2-\cos^2(x)}\sin^2(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, closed-form

I need help with this integral:
$$I = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2 -\cos^2(x)}\sin^2(x) dx$$

Unfortunately, neither Mathematica nor WolframAlpha are able to compute it.
WolframAlpha gives the approximate value of the integral as
$$I \approx 0.394862$$
and the integrand looks something like this:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Umv.jpg)

I would greatly appreciate, if anyone knew a closed form solution to this.

Comment: Why do you expect a closed form?

Comment: I don't have a particular reason to believe there is a closed form solution, I only hope there is one. I guess I am missing a bit of intuition in questions like that.

Sorry for the mistake, I corrected it now.

Comment: @stepze Can you tell that from where have you taken this integral